# Linking Ecommerce app with existing Ecommerce store

Tags: flutter, dart, shopify, adobe-xd, shopify-api

Currently designed the UI of an Ecommerce app I am developing from an existing Shopify Store. I took my designs to Supernova(the design to code platform) and was wondering how I could incorporate Shopify API in the app so I can display my products in the app and it is linked to the Shopify Store. Hope someone can help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

Get yourself into the Storefront API. You can connect your Flutter shop to your Shopify store and do checkouts with it.